# Simple Telnet console that listens and accepts connections

Tags: c#, console-application, telnet, tcplistener

I am new to Telnet and C# and  I am trying to create a simple console program. I need a TCP listener that starts up, listens for incoming networking connections and sends a response back. I don’t really care for the incoming message but I need to accept it so the client thinks that the connection was successful. This TCP listener will respond with “Hello”. 
I just need to make sure that it starts up cleanly and close the TCP listener gracefully without throwing any exceptions. I need to use “Telnet localhost 9090” to connect to the TCP listener on your laptop on port 9090.

Can you help?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: I used the example code that is found on MSDNs TCPListener Class example page. It is the same as the answer provided by Jaycee. I don't know however what @Jaycee second set of code is for though

Comment: @RuvimSkochko I've slightly amended the MSDN example to listen on the correct port and send a response. The second complete console app example is of a client that can be run separately as a quick test of the server

Comment: @Jaycee Ok, I see what you did now. I read on the MSDN site that with their example code, the stop method doesnt close any accepted connections. How can I close the accepted connections (for lack of better words) "gracefully"?

Comment: @RuvimSkochko It's just a case of ensuring  client.Close(); gets called for any client you have accepted. Not sure what you are doing but if you just call Stop it does not mean whatever connections you currently have open will be closed. You might want to implement something to tidy up - keep a list of the TcpClient you have created and run through the list in the finally section calling Close on each - and then call Stop. This tidies things up in the event of an exception. How the server manages client connnections is app specific.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [TCPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class. The example echoes the string sent to it from the client provided in the second set of code so it sends the response Howdy. You can test this  when you run the client code below, which calls **Socket.Receive** to get the string back from the server:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace tcplistener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            Int32 port = 9090;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop. 
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Hello!");

                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client. 
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }


        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();

        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tcpconnect
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connect1("127.0.0.1", 9090);

            Console.Read();
        }

        // Synchronous connect using IPAddress to resolve the  
        // host name. 
        public static void Connect1(string host, int port)
        {
            IPAddress[] IPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);

            Console.WriteLine("Establishing Connection to {0}",
                host);
            s.Connect(IPs[0], port);

            byte[] howdyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Howdy");
            s.Send(howdyBytes);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
            s.Receive(buffer);
            Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
            Console.WriteLine("Connection established");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to try your example in .NET Core, but it seems that they have not implemented server.AcceptSocket() or server.AcceptTcpClient(); How could I work around using these calls?

Comment: The source code for .net core is in github, I checked the TcpListener class and both those methods are there: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/TCPListener.cs

Answer (score 6):

You can use this Simple Telnet Server I found on Internet: https://github.com/robertripoll/TelnetServer

You can have this code as a base for the program you're planning to build.

Comment: I've just updated the link but can you add some more context about this solution? At the moment it's pretty much a link-only answer.